# How to match "command line argument" style strings with regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate a string I use in one of my applications, and the structure of it is basically the same as linux command line arguments.

E.G
`-m -b -s` etc...

I'm basically trying to make the pattern;

- No space at the beginning but allow spaces inbetween words.
- There must be a space before a `-` if it isn't the first `-`.
- There should be no limit to how many you can enter as long as they fit the pattern. For example these would all be fine; `-m -fd -optional` but something like this wouldnt be; `-m-fd teststring`

I managed to get as far as `^-[a-zA-Z]\s` but I'm not sure how to make this repeat! This also doesn't work on flags longer than 1 character and also has some issues with spaces!

Comment: To match such a line you could use `^-[^\s-][^-]*(?:\s-[^\s-][^-]*)*$` and to extract, you may use `(?<!\S)-[^\s-][^-]*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry I only got around to testing it now. Yes it does! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match and *validate* such a line you could use

```
^-[^\s-][^-]*(?:\s-[^\s-][^-]*)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z78Ipm/1).

To *extract* each option, you may use

```
(?<!\S)-[^\s-][^-]*
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z78Ipm/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[^\s-][^-]*` - any char other than whitespace and `-` and then 0 or more chars othee than `-`
- `(?:\s-[^\s-][^-]*)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

  - `\s` - a whitespace
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[^\s-][^-]*` - any char other than whitespace and `-` and then 0 or more chars othee than `-`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Hey I found a bit of a flaw in this. With the example `-m -fd teststring` it matches when teststring should require a dash before it. Any ideas? :)

Comment: @Borassign Maybe you want `^-[^\s-]+(?:\s-[^\s-]+)*$` and `(?<!\S)-[^\s-]+`?